# how to compare two csv files and write 1 or 0 in a new file with python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I would like to request some question.
I want to compare 2 csv files. The source file with all attribute values in a comma separated form. 
source csv file contains like this

> advapi32.dll,comctl32.dll,comdlg32.dll,gdi32.dll,gdiplus.dll,hal.dll,imagehlp.dll,kernel32.dll,mpr.dll,mscoree.dll,msi.dll,msvcrt.dll,mswsock.dll,ndis.sys,netapi32.dll,ntdll.dll,ntoskrnl.exe,ole32.dll,oleaut32.dll,oledlg.dll,opengl32.dll,psapi.dll,rpcrt4.dll,setupapi.dll,shell32.dll,shlwapi.dll,tapi32.dll,ucc12.dll,user32,user32.dll,wininet.dll,winmm.dll,winspool.drv,ws2_32.dll

the second csv file is

> advapi32.dll,gdi32.dll,imagehlp.dll,kernel32.dll,msvcrt.dll,mswsock.dll,ntdll.dll,ole32.dll,oleaut32.dll

I would like to write 1 if the value of second file contains in source, otherwise 0 to a new file.
Example of output csv file is:

> advapi32.dll,comctl32.dll,comdlg32.dll,gdi32.dll,gdiplus.dll,hal.dll,imagehlp.dll,kernel32.dll,mpr.dll,mscoree.dll,msi.dll,msvcrt.dll,mswsock.dll,ndis.sys,netapi32.dll,ntdll.dll,ntoskrnl.exe,ole32.dll,oleaut32.dll,oledlg.dll,opengl32.dll,psapi.dll,rpcrt4.dll,setupapi.dll,shell32.dll,shlwapi.dll,tapi32.dll,ucc12.dll,user32,user32.dll,wininet.dll,winmm.dll,winspool.drv,ws2_32.dll
>
> 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1

Can someone help me please because I am a very new to python programming.

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions in stack overflow

Comment: ["Can someone help me" is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Python question but I see no python code. Do some work and ask us when you are really stuck. Btw what does "if the value of second file contains in source" mean?

Comment: @RaphaMex For example, output `1` since `advapi32.dll` in second string exists in first string.

Comment: Learning about `split(",")`, some for loops, and the `in` keyword will get you far @Cho

Comment: @RaphaMex .. yes I do understand what you mean RaphaMex . I am really do not know what should I use to compare these two files(for example: list or something like that).

Comment: @cricket_007 ..thank you very much for your valuable advice Cricket :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then your shorter dll list is some sort of "inventory" (aka possible) and you want to go through the longer list to see if it is in the shorter list. If this is correct then something like this would do it (using `split` and `in` as the comments suggest):

```
possible = "advapi32.dll,gdi32.dll,imagehlp.dll,kernel32.dll,msvcrt.dll,mswsock.dll,ntdll.dll,ole32.dll,oleaut32.dll"
test = "advapi32.dll,comctl32.dll,comdlg32.dll,gdi32.dll,gdiplus.dll,hal.dll,imagehlp.dll,kernel32.dll,mpr.dll,mscoree.dll,msi.dll,msvcrt.dll,mswsock.dll,ndis.sys,netapi32.dll,ntdll.dll,ntoskrnl.exe,ole32.dll,oleaut32.dll,oledlg.dll,opengl32.dll,psapi.dll,rpcrt4.dll,setupapi.dll,shell32.dll,shlwapi.dll,tapi32.dll,ucc12.dll,user32,user32.dll,wininet.dll,winmm.dll,winspool.drv,ws2_32.dll"

possible_list = possible.split(",")
does_match = []
for t in test.split(","):
    if t in possible_list:
        does_match.append("1")
    else:
        does_match.append("0")
print(",".join(does_match))
```

This is just the basic idea how you would approach it. What I leave you as an exercise is to read the data from the file and to write it back, but for this you find plenty of answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was looking for. And I finish your exercise as for my homework. Thanks a lot Hansapla.

Comment: @ChoCho: yes, that looks correct, glad I could help

Comment: I appreciate your help  :)